# How to fix the error "In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package" in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, heroku, composer-php

On localhost every thing work okay but when I try to deploy laravel project to heroku I get this error:

`message "In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package"`

I have tried the next things to fix this error but they are not working for me

```
composer require laravel/ui 

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth


php artisan cache:clear 

php artisan config:cache 

php artisan route:cache
```

Manually clear the .php files within the bootstrap/cache folder and then php artisan config:cache.

And all of this solutions didn't work for me

Comment: Did you install on the heroku server or install locally then copy everything to heroku?

Comment: Try php artisan view:clear

Comment: What database that use MYSQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Postgresql ..@Eng_Farghly

Comment: i push the project to heroku repostery in github ...so every thing i have installed in vendor didn't included so i had to run composer update on the server consol but that didn't work .....@Snapey

Comment: The answer of @kim-hallberg work successfully special thanks for him that help us to find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of `laravel/ui` are you trying to install? The newest - `4.x` at the time of writing, is not compatible with Laravel 8. So you want to install `3.x` for a version that supports Laravel 8.

```php
composer require laravel/ui:^3.0
```

Comment: Are you test this solution on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, here's a [demo](https://aqueous-mountain-39858.herokuapp.com/), and the [source](https://github.com/thinkverse/heroku-demo) for it. It's a fresh Laravel 8 project with Laravel UI running on Heroku.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. But I'd rather hear from @skrat-gh and if it worked for them. And if it did, I'd ask them to mark the answer as the solution for other users who might have the same issue in the future. 

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't do it...laravel/ui in composer.json ="^3.0" but when i run composer show in heroku console the version ="^3.4.1" ....@KimHallberg

Comment: @SkratGh Do you commit the `vendor` folder? That sometimes causes issues on Heroku from what I've heard. If you do you might want to add `vendor` to your `gitignore` file and stop tracking it.

Comment: the vendor folder is in the gitignore file ..@KimHallberg

Comment: Then I'm sorry @SkratGh, I'm not sure how to fix your issue, sorry I couldn't solve it for you, hope you find a solution somewhere though. 